# link style scheme not working

Tags: html, css

```
a.mO {color: white; cursor:pointer; margin-left:10px; font-weight:400; font-size:12px; display:block; border-top:1px solid #300;}
```

---

```
a.mO:link {
color: white; cursor:pointer; margin-left:10px; font-weight:400; font-size:12px; display:block; border-top:1px solid #300;
}
a.mO:visited {
color: white; cursor:pointer; margin-left:10px; font-weight:600; font-size:16px; display:block; border-top:1px solid #300;
}

a.mO:hover {
color: white; cursor:pointer; margin-left:10px; font-weight:900; font-size:12px; display:block; border-top:1px solid #300;
}

a.mO:active{
color: white; cursor:pointer; margin-left:10px; font-weight:900; font-size:14px; display:block; border-top:2px solid #300;
}
```

---

The first code works. But as soon as I replace it with the second one it stops working.

My html is :

```
<div><a class="mO"   onclick="loadPage(31);">ABCD Status</a></div>
```

Thanks for help...

Comment: Can you please elaborate any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of these will not work unless you include the `href` attribute (it isn't a link other wise):

```
<a class="mO" href="#" onclick="loadPage(31);">ABCD Status</a>
```

You may also want to `return false;` after calling the function, to prevent the page from jumping to to top. You can either do `onclick="loadPage(31); return false;"`, or `onclick="return loadPage(31);"`, and have it returning `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to

```
<div><a class="mO" href="#"  onclick="loadPage(31);">ABCD Status</a></div>
```

and see if that helps any.